# How to get a basic direvent watcher working?

Tags: nixos

I have read through the direvent [documentation](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/direvent/manual/index.html) and am trying to get a simple watch working. Since I am having so much trouble with it, I am wondering if the issue has to do with the fact that the system I am using is nixos.

Here is the simple watcher file, `watcher`, I've created:

```
watcher {
  path ./dir;
  command "echo $file";
}
```

I run it in the foreground, so I can see the output, with `direvent --foreground watcher`. Once it's running, I create a file in `dir`, thus creating an event for it to respond to. However, it fails with the following output:

```
$ direvent --foreground watcher
direvent: [INFO] direvent 5.2 started
direvent: [ERROR] process 8552 failed with status 127
direvent: [ERROR] process 8555 failed with status 127
direvent: [ERROR] process 8557 failed with status 127
```

Since 127 usually means 'command not found', I tried specifying the path to echo, i.e. running this watcher instead:

```
watcher {
  path ./dir;
  command "/run/current-system/sw/bin/echo $file";
}
```

Then the output still gives an error, albeit a different one:

```
$ direvent --foreground watcher
direvent: [INFO] direvent 5.2 started
direvent: [ERROR] process 8645 failed with status 1
direvent: [ERROR] process 8651 failed with status 1
direvent: [ERROR] process 8652 failed with status 1
```

So the failure is now with status 1. I am not sure what to try next. I'm wondering if this issue is due to the fact that I am running nixos. Anyone know what I might try next to get direvent working?

Answer (score 1):

`direvent` has two other flag that may be useful for you.

`--debug`(`-d`) to give extra information.

There's also `--lint`(`t`) that check the configuration file for errors, but I suspect this isn't your issue if `direvent` is running.

Source: https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/direvent/manual/direvent.html